# Not getting any output from this HTML and JS

Tags: javascript, html

I'm learning the basics of web programming. I have this HTML and this .js:

```
<!--index.html-->
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Client</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    </head>
    <body>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="client.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>

/* client.js */
function currentDate(){
    var now = newDate();
    document.writeln(now.toDateString());
    document.write("hey!");
}

currentDate();
```

I'm running the index.html on my localhost and it shows nothing. Empty page. What am I missing here? I have no idea what is wrong. I expect it to write out a date and the word "hey!".

Comment: Did you added an `script` tag?

Comment: See the code. There is a script tag linking to client.js

Comment: [Open the browser's console](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/8525/how-to-open-the-javascript-console-in-different-browsers) and look at the error message.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are missing a space:

```
var now = new Date();
```

Comment: Yup, the console showed it too.